# How do you beat a zerg player that roach rushes using protoss?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-protoss

What is the easiest and fastest way? I'm definitely slower than the zerg player. I usually lose because I cheese(troll), and get discovered, but I usually don't lose. What is the best build order to defend roach rush, because I'm used to cheesing and not good at making a good base?

Comment: There are a multitude of different kinds of roach rushes (7, 5, etc). Are you having trouble with specific ones, or just Roach rushes in general?

Comment: Roach rush in general.

Comment: Did you try googling an answer? I typed in Roach Rush defend and got a bunch of results

Comment: @eyeofthehawks that's NOT an acceptable answer here. Telling someone to look on Google doesn't help in any way.

Comment: @shanodin That would be why it is in a comment.

Comment: @eyeofthehawks [relevant meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8302/on-trivial-questions-from-new-users/8309#8309) and a quote from it "Why can anyone make that comment in the first place?
Because they have the knowledge. They know how to search for something successfully. And that's the very knowledge we should be giving to the asker. That's what we're here for, that's how we help."

Comment: Regardless, I personally don't believe this question is suitable for the format of this site.  Starcraft goes through constant meta shifts, and there are infinite variables from game to game that can alter the 'answer' in this case.

Comment: I've gone through this same argument before in league(even openned a meta on it http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8224/18146), just provide a relevant answer for now, and update it is the general response. Of course not alot of people do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I counter the 7 roach rush build?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10131/how-do-i-counter-the-7-roach-rush-build)  (also http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75237)

Comment: Metagame shifts won't really change the openers.  You either open gateway pressure, stargate, robo, or forge FE.  Each of them needs to have an answer to roach all-ins, otherwise they're not good builds

Comment: "I usually lose" [...] "but I usually don't lose". Have you tried playing the campaign at least? Or vs. the AI more then 3 times?

Comment: You said 'I usually lose, but I usually don't lose' in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what roach timing you're referring to.

There are many possible timings, on one base, two bases, three-base roach max, etc.

Also, you haven't specified if you're opening gateway first or forge FE.

Given that the metagame right now is for gateway openings, you should scout on 9 or 13.  If you see he's on a single base you drop 2 extra gateways and make a sentry and stalkers to handle the pressure.

If it's a 2base roach all-in then you'll know by the empty third base (can be scouted with a probe, MSC, hallucinated phx, etc.

Basically you just identify that the zerg isn't droning and make extra gates or boost out immortals to handle the problem.

If you forge FE it's harder ... you need to make a bunch of cannons (like 4) and boost out a few sentries to keep them from getting into your natural.  May need to pull probes to keep the roaches from killing your cannons.